# VSTO: accessing CommandBarButton with variable yields invalid reference - Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am trying to add a custom button to one of Word's `CommandBar`'s, and then later change them to be visible or invisible. As prescribed in [some tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723154(v=vs.90).aspx) that I have seen, I make sure to store the button in a class variable so my item isn't de-allocated upon garbage collection. I know the correct way to access the item later, as stated in the tutorial above, but what is wrong with the way I try below in the right click handler:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Office.CommandBar textContextMenu;
    private Office.CommandBarButton exampleMenuItem;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // keep track of the menu for later
        textContextMenu = this.Application.CommandBars["Text"];
        // add a right click handler
        this.Application.WindowBeforeRightClick += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler(application_WindowBeforeRightClick);

        AddToToolbar();
    }

    private void AddToToolbar()
    {
        // Add a button to the command bar
        exampleMenuItem = (Office.CommandBarButton)textContextMenu.Controls.Add(
            Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
            missing,
            missing,
            1,
            true);

        exampleMenuItem.Caption = "Test Button";
        exampleMenuItem.Tag = "testButton";
    }

    public void application_WindowBeforeRightClick(Word.Selection selection, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        // attempting to access the variable here throws the COM exception
        exampleMenuItem.Visible = false;
        // ... but, as in the tutorial, I can access the button like this:
        var exampleButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)textContextMenu.FindControl(
            buttonType, 
            missing, 
            "testButton");
        exampleButton.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I've looked up the VBA exception 0x800A01A8 - as far as I know, I'm not trying to access a COM object that doesn't exist, but what am I missing? Why can't I access the button from a variable after it has been added in this way?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command bars were deprecated, you need to use the Fluent UI controls instead. What Word version do you have installed on the PC?

See [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

Comment: I'm using VS2013 and the Word 2013. The functionality for command bars must still be there; using `CommandBarButton.FindControl` and then setting attributes, as in the code above, works fine for me.